# Given 3 sets, find all triples with no more three repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

I have three disjoint sets of cardinality $n$ each, $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, $Y=\{y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\}$, and $Z=\{z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n\}$. Let $T=X\times Y\times Z$. In $T$, we have $n^3$ elements. Let $M\subset T$ such that no element of a triple of $M$ occurs in more than three triples of $M$. What is the maximal value of $|M|$, denoted $|M|^*$?

For example, for $n=3$, I can find $|M|^*=9$. For $n=4$, $|M|^*=10$.

I know that $|M|^*=O(n)$ but I cannot find the exact value of $|M|^*$.

Comment: You could have $|M|=0$. It sounds like you're looking for the *maximal* value of $|M|$?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: What is it that stops the answer being $3n$?

Comment: I think we can only say that $|M|^*\leq3n$ but we cannot find it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this arrangement of 3 copies of all elements?

If you put the $x_i$ in order:
$$x_1,x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2,x_2,x_3,.....$$

and put the $y_i$ in order:
$$y_1,y_2, ... y_n,y_1,y_2, ... y_n,...$$

and put the $z_i$ in random order.

Then pick the triples of $M$ by choosing the $k$th element of each list.